# ASP.NET C# Silly error when reaching for RSS XML File on the web

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss

I'm making a webform that will go to a site, grab the rss feeds in xml format and read them into a XmlTextReader to be formated and displayed in my site.

I have this line which takes care of the reaching the other site

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/feed/");
```

When I run this from my localHost it runs fine. But once it gets publish on a 1and1 server it fails with the following error.

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 72.246.94.16:80

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 72.246.94.16:80

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Any ideas what can it be?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably being blocked by an outbound firewall at 1&1.

Contact 1&1 and ask them to disable it, or switch to a better host. (you get what you pay for)

Comment: hahah, thats the answer I was scared of!
each time I have to deal with them I'm reminded of how much they suck.... next time will choose better, hopefully.

Thanks!

Comment: ok. I found this bit of relevant info.

CAS will grant access to only critical resources that hold particular CAS permissions. In shared hosting the following permissions will be given:

 ... 
 WebPermission to perform HTTP requests, e.g. to use external XML Web Services. (The access must be done using a proxy server ntproxyus.lxa.perfora.net on port 3128)